# Enable setTimeout when the mobile has screen switched off

Tags: javascript, angular

I have on the client side (mobile) a timer (setTimeout()) which triggers refreshing the token on the server side by sending a post message to the server.
That timer does not seem to trigger sending a message to the server when the screen timeout on my mobile is on and the screen is black.
How can I enable triggering even if the mobile has the screen switched off.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a a way for angular to know when a page is locked. You could track any input or page movements instead and reset a timeout timer so that if the page stays idle for a while you could send a request to the server. That being said you would probably want the page timeout to be decently long to avoid closing a session while a user is still using the page. What you can also do is have a warning message pop up when the timeout is reached that prompts the user to say they are still using the page, if they click yes reset the timer again otherwise close the session.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by locked page. setTimeout method simply does not work when the screen is off. Is there any remedy for that ?

Comment: @user19564787 Have you tried OnDestroy?